# Pre-render angular's template to re-use them

Tags: html, angularjs, templates, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an HTML structure with a list of tables like this

```
 <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <table>
       <td ng-repeat="row2 in rows2">
          <tr ng-repeat="col in cols">
              {{blablabla}}
          </tr>
       </td>
    </table>
 </div>
```

The table is always quite the same, but Angular just redraw it every times (for each elements in 'rows'), which leads to some performance issues.
Is there a way to tell angular to pre render the table in the middle, and then display the list ?

Comment: Have a look at [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce).

Comment: if anyone else winds up here, the bindonce functionality from the comment above has landed in angular as of 1.3 - http://swirlycheetah.com/native-bind-once-in-angularjs-1-3/

Comment: @aron.duby -- Link died. [Repro from archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160815072005/http://swirlycheetah.com/native-bind-once-in-angularjs-1-3/).